# Nested MySQL queries with 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables as below with their columns:

```
  links: authID1, authID2, pubID
  authors: authorName, authorID
  publications: pubID, pubTitle
```

I wish to obtain name pairs of collaborating authors and I have been able to do so with the code below:

```
     SELECT 
       o.authorName AS 'authname1',
       p.authorName AS 'authname2'
      FROM links e
       JOIN authors  o
         ON (e.authID1 = o.authorID)
        JOIN authors  p
          ON (e.authID2 = p.authorID)
             JOIN  publications j 
                ON (e.pubID = j.pubID) 
                   WHERE ( j.pubTitle LIKE '%computers%')
```

My current dilemma is how to obtain the name pairs and execute a **LIMIT** function when obtaining records to match from the publications table.

I have been able to do this with two tables as below, but I can't figure out with 3 tables and calling one table (authors table) twice.
this is an example of what I wish to do :

```
     SELECT e.authID1, e.authID2
       FROM links AS e
          INNER JOIN
           (SELECT pubID
             FROM publications 
               WHERE ( j.pubTitle LIKE '%computers%')
                  LIMIT 4) as j
          ON e.pubID = j.pubID
```

Comment: Have you tried to substitute the table publications with the subquery, as you've done in the second query, also in the first query? What is the problem doing that? Have you got problem with the correct syntax?

Comment: @kiks yes I am having a problem with the syntax, I did not write the attempts here as it would take much space of the question text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only on the SQL syntax, this should be the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   o.authorName AS 'authname1',
   p.authorName AS 'authname2'
FROM links e
INNER JOIN authors  o
ON e.authID1 = o.authorID
INNER JOIN authors  p
ON e.authID2 = p.authorID
INNER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT pubID
             FROM publications 
             WHERE ( j.pubTitle LIKE '%computers%')
             LIMIT 4) as j  
ON e.pubID = j.pubID
```

I added 2 `DISTINCT` to be sure you're not retrieving duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to return author name. Exp:

```
create function get_author_name (id int ) returns varchar(255)
BEGIN
     DECLARE author_name varchar(255);
     SELECT authorName  INTO author_name
     FROM authors        
     WHERE authorID = id;
     RETURN author_name;
END;
```

then use it

```
 SELECT e.authID1, e.authID2, get_author_name(e.authID1) as author1, get_author_name(e.authID2) as author2
   FROM links AS e
      INNER JOIN
       (SELECT pubID
         FROM publications 
           WHERE ( j.pubTitle LIKE '%computers%')
              LIMIT 4) as j
      ON e.pubID = j.pubID
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless